# what is latent feature in collaborative filtering

Tags: terminology, recommender-system

What are latent features in collaborative filtering algorithms? I've been reading about it but don't really understand it. Are latent features the learned matrices from matrix factorization; the similarities between the 2 factorized matrices?

Comment: Can you give example of particular algorithm you have in mind?

Comment: I'm not really sure what algorithm it is. I'm using a collaborative filtering technique using matrix factorization. I guess the most popular example of it is for recommending movies. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are talking about the most simple matrix factorization algorithm, as described in the [Matrix Factorization Techniques for Recommender Systems](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-[Netflix].pdf) paper by Koren, Bell and Volinsky. They describe how the matrix $R_{n \times k}$ (users $\times$ movie ratings) can be decomposed to $P_{n \times m}$ and $Q_{m \times k}$ matrices, so for $i$-th movie and $u$-th user, we can predict the movie rating $\hat{r}_{iu} = q_i^Tp_u$ and based on this, make recommendations. This means that each user and movie are described by vectors of latent variables $p$ and $q$, each of length $k$. You can hear people saying that "users are represented in $k$ latent dimensions". So the matrices $P$ and $Q$ store the referred latent variables. ["Latent variable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable) is an unobservable variable, as compared, for example, to ratings that are observable, but some of them are unknown.

Comment: Ah ok, so the latent features that I'm talking about are in P and Q which are learned after training. Thanks!